# Hibernate Apache Derby Custom Sequence

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to investigate the generator class in the ID sequence generation of Hibernate.

I tried to use the sequence generator on a very simple mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.test">
    <class name="Customer" table="Customer">
        <id name="id" column="ID" type="long">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">CUSTOMER_SEQUENCE</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string" column="CUSTOMER_NAME" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am using apache derby, the ID column in the customer table is justa simple long datatype.

But when I try to execute a simple save, I am encountering below error.

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: SEQUENCE 'CUSTOMER_SEQUENCE' does not exist.
Does this mean that Apache Derby does not support Sequence Generation?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Derby doesn't support sequence generation. Quote from official [Derby FAQ](http://db.apache.org/derby/faq.html#identity):

> Derby supports generated "identity"
>   columns; examples are in the Reference
>   Guide. The IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL function
>   returns the most recently assigned
>   number.
>
> Work is underway to add SEQUENCE
>   support to Derby 10.6.

Answer (score 2):

Derby now supports sequence generation, as follows:

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefsqljcreatesequence.html

Comment: If you are using a version of hibernate before 3.6.0 Final you might run into this issue : https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5427

Comment: Sure, I had this bug, and updated to Hibernate 3.6.10.Final ;)