# hibernate:Derby does not support sequence prior to release 10.6.1.0

Tags: java, hibernate, derby

I am using hibernate for Apache Derby DB. When I am going to build my application I am getting error

**Derby does not support sequence prior to release 10.6.1.0**

I am using below hibernate and derby jars into my application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.11.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

From this [link](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefsqljcreatesequence.html) that sequences are now supported by Apache Derby DB.

Followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529348/hibernate-apache-derby-custom-sequence) but didn't find much help on this issue.

Entity Class is as below:-

```
package rest.food.ordering.model;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="SERVING_LOCATION")
public class ServingLocation {  

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SER_LOC_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SER_LOC_SEQ", sequenceName = "SERVING_LOCATION_SEQUENCE", allocationSize=1,initialValue=1)
    @Column(name="LOCATION_ID",nullable = false)
    private BigInteger locationId;

    @Column(name="LOCATION_NAME",nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String locationName;

    public BigInteger getLocationId() {
        return locationId;
    }

    public void setLocationId(BigInteger locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }

    public String getLocationName() {
        return locationName;
    }

    public void setLocationName(String locationName) {
        this.locationName = locationName;
    }

}
```

StackTrace of error is below:-

```
17:02:30,934 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137) org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=rest.food.ordering.model.ServingLocation]

17:02:30,935 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:123)

17:02:30,935 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createIdentifierGenerator(SimpleValue.java:213)

17:02:30,935 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:323)

17:02:30,935 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)

17:02:30,935 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at rest.food.ordering.utils.HibernateUtils.getSessionFactoryObject(HibernateUtils.java:44)

17:02:30,935 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at rest.food.ordering.dao.FoodOrderingDaoImpl.<clinit>(FoodOrderingDaoImpl.java:21)

17:02:30,935 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at rest.food.ordering.configuration.AppBeansConfig.getFoodOrderingDaoObj(AppBeansConfig.java:14)

17:02:30,935 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at rest.food.ordering.configuration.AppBeansConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f82ba1fe.CGLIB$getFoodOrderingDaoObj$0(<generated>)

17:02:30,935 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at rest.food.ordering.configuration.AppBeansConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f82ba1fe$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ce1e0aa.invoke(<generated>)

17:02:30,935 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)

17:02:30,936 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)

17:02:30,936 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at rest.food.ordering.configuration.AppBeansConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f82ba1fe.getFoodOrderingDaoObj(<generated>)

17:02:30,936 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

17:02:30,936 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

17:02:30,936 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

17:02:30,936 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

17:02:30,936 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)

17:02:30,936 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)

17:02:30,936 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)

17:02:30,936 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)

17:02:30,936 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)

17:02:30,936 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)

17:02:30,936 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)

17:02:30,937 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)

17:02:30,937 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)

17:02:30,937 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)

17:02:30,937 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1145)

17:02:30,937 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1069)

17:02:30,937 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)

17:02:30,937 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)

17:02:30,937 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)

17:02:30,937 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)

17:02:30,937 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)

17:02:30,937 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)

17:02:30,937 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)

17:02:30,937 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)

17:02:30,938 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)

17:02:30,938 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)

17:02:30,938 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)

17:02:30,938 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1145)

17:02:30,938 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1069)

17:02:30,938 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)

17:02:30,938 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)

17:02:30,938 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)

17:02:30,938 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)

17:02:30,938 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)

17:02:30,938 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)

17:02:30,938 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)

17:02:30,938 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)

17:02:30,939 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)

17:02:30,939 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)

17:02:30,939 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)

17:02:30,939 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)

17:02:30,939 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)

17:02:30,939 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)

17:02:30,939 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)

17:02:30,939 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)

17:02:30,939 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)

17:02:30,939 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)

17:02:30,939 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)

17:02:30,939 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)

17:02:30,939 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)

17:02:30,940 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

17:02:30,940 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

17:02:30,940 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

17:02:30,940 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

17:02:30,940 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17:02:30,940 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

17:02:30,940 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137) Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Derby does not support sequence prior to release 10.6.1.0

17:02:30,940 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect.getSequenceNextValString(DerbyDialect.java:136)

17:02:30,940 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.configure(SequenceGenerator.java:110)

17:02:30,940 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator.configure(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:55)

17:02:30,941 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:117)

17:02:30,941 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 137)  ... 67 more
```

Help me on this issue.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/DerbyDialect.html: this class is deprecated. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/DerbyTenSevenDialect.html probably is the dialect you need, and supporting sequences.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks Sir !!! You saved my day by pointing out my silly mistake.